# Volumetric Lighting

Tags: light, volumetrics

I have Blender version 2.74, and I just can't find a way for myself to create volumetric light, I tried setting in world properties the **Volumetric Scatter** and then at the bottom enabling **Homogeneous**, but the render takes way too much time and still no volumetric light, I searched in youtube in hope of finding a tutorial but most of them are outdated or doesn't work for me. Help highly appreciated

What I basicly want is, I have a door and I want the Light(volumetric)rays to be seen coming from that door.

Comment: Could you be more precise about what is not working? Could you add screenshot of your test scene showing your world's settings and the "failing" render preview?

Comment: I am not even sure that I am using the correct method, to be honest

Comment: Are you rendering on GPU? and if so,  what kind?

Comment: Nope, only on CPU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from a simple scene like the one below:

[image]

Set up the lights. In this case I put a simple **spot lamp**.

[image]

Now **add a Volumetric Scatter shader** to the World's material volume output.

[image]

Light scattering will dim the overall light of the scene, as some bunces "get lost" while trying to reach the camera. If before they were running undisturebed trough the air, now the have to penetrate in a sort of thick fog, so we'll need a stronger light to see something.

I'll start from lowering the the **density** of the shader to 0.5 and at the same time **increasing the strenght** of the lamp by two orders (x100).

Result:

[image]

You'll need to increase considerably the number of samples to get rid of the noise.

Comment: Thanks, I would suppose my light was too weak for me to see it.  But is there a way I can create a volumetric light in Cycles without affecting the other surrounding lights, like the halo setting in the Blender Redner ?

Comment: Yep; Thanks for help, setting the light to a higher value, made it